# How to bake a roughness map from a Sculpted mesh?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

In this case, I have a little lizard critter I sculpted in Blender, and I have baked the normal map and AO, but I didn't saw an option for roughness. I wanted a roughness map to make the scales on him shine, but not the gaps in-between them. Is there a way to bake that info onto a map in blender?

Comment: I think there isn't direct way to bake pass from existing ones; as an option you could try to grab Z channel from normal map, adjust with RGB curves and bake that into map. Note though this might work in some areas while not work in others

Comment: Hmm....I see. Well, I had hoped there was something.